# How to use mpi4py read

Tags: python, mpi

I am having trouble reading with mpi4py.  I have opened the file and read it, however then I want to do manipulation in python with list.   I get an error that the datatype (mpi4py) datatype object does not support.   How to I read it into an object python supports, or convert it?

I use MPI.File_Seek(block_start) wherr block_start is nprocs/size  then        MPI.File_read. (after opening the file with MPI).  It takes a buffer argument,  im not certain what that is, but I use a btyearray of size block_start -block_end.      I have figured out how to use python to then turn the bytearray into a sting and do the manipulation i need to, then turn it back into a bytearray and print.   I am wondering if their is a more efficient way.

The task is to read financial tick data (date,price,volume) with date coming in on microseconds of form yyyymmdd:hh:mm:ss.ssssss, and to identify malformed lines.   I succedded sequentially with a small file using python sequentially.   We are required to use Python with mpi4py.   The task seems simple, however mlst of us are very inexperienced programers (in fact I am taking my first programming course simultaneosly).  However, we are not learning programming in the class,.

Comment: Can you please edit this question to include some more info about how you read this file. I have a suspicion it's not confined to `mpi` but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you.  I updated the question.